# Converting an argparse bash script into a python script

Tags: python, bash, ide, argparse

Consider the bash script below. The script argparse_test.py is an argparse script with various variables.

```
python -u argparse_test.py \
  --is_training 3 \
  --root_path ./dataset/ \
  --data_path data.csv \
  -/test_$seq_len'_'196.log
```

How would I convert this bash script to a python script so that I could run it in a python IDE with the various variables?

Comment: what does your main function look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `bash` input

```
python -u argparse_test.py \
  --is_training 3 \
  --root_path ./dataset/ \
  --data_path data.csv \
  -/test_$seq_len'_'196.log
```

should produce a `sys.argv` that looks like

```
['argparse_test.py', '--is_training', '3', '--root_path ./dataset/','--data_path', 'data.csv', '-/test_$seq_len'_'196.log']
```

that's a rough guess; bash may be handling the slashes different (I'm on a windows machine now).

"running in an IDE" is a vague request.

Some IDE have a `run` menu item, and a way of specifying commandline arguments (usually in a separate menu setup item).

If you have code that setups up a parser:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
...
```

the line

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

reads that `sys.argv[1:]` and parses it.  So an alternative way to use the parser is to provide the equivalent list of strings directly:

```
argv = ['--is_training','3',...]
args = parser.parse_args(argv)
```

If you can modify the script, you could add a couple of displays

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

and after the `parse_args`

```
print(args)
```

`args` will be a `argparse.Namespace` object that should display like

```
Namespace(is_training=3, root_path='./dataset/', data_path='data.csv', ...)

vars(args)
```

is a `dict` with the same keys and values

Any python object with the same attributes should be have the same as `args` in the rest of your code.

I have a feeling this answer is too long and detailed - because of the vagueness of the question.